# Issue with overflow in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I'm having an issue with IE7 related to overflow. http://www.photocrayze.com/photos

On Google Chrome, Firefox, or any browser that's not IE7, this layout works as intended. The tags (look specifically at the photos 'City People' and 'Kaleidoscopic') are cut off at the edges and set to half opacity. On mouseover, the edges are revealed and set to full opacity.

However, in IE7, when you mouseover a photo, `div.photo-tags-inner` expands and messes up the layout. I'm not sure how to explain this better... but how can I fix this issue?

Also, it seems like setting the opacity to 0.5 doesn't work in IE8 (but works in IE7 and IE9 and other browsers)...

```
zoom: 1;
-ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0.5);
opacity: 0.5;
filter: alpha(opacity=0.5);
```

Comment: How is that comment constructive?

Comment: if you notice you have an overflow problem in Firefox also but you dont notice it as much because the opacity it might be awidth problem of the overlaying css elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving `.photo-tags-inner` `position:absolute` and `left:0` fixed the issue in IE7 and also works fine in other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

in your css style

```
.photo-browser tr td .photo-info .photo-tags {
margin: 0.5em auto auto;
opacity: 0.5;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
width: 200px;
}
```

get rid of overflow hidden and it should work. Next time also use firexfox's firebug to play around with styling to get teh desired output. But then I notice then the horizontal scroll bar comes up that may mean you need to some more digging to find out how to get rid of that.